# Why is my query performing a Clustered Index Scan

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that tries to find all records within a certain bounding box [geocode lookup].

After running the query plan through the RedGate profiler it spends an awfully large amount of time inside a Clustered Index Scan (below) (offending query at the bottom of question).  This is my slowest running query and I guess there is something wrong with it because of this final step taking so long?

[image]

After having looked around SO and Google I decided to include all columns of the table inside my index. Here are what indexes I have

- PK on the Id.
- Index on [UTC_UPDATED Desc, North, East, South, West] [includes all other columns to try avoid scan]
- Index on [UTC_UPDATED Desc, Source Desc]

Query:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON; SET ANSI_PADDING ON; SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON; SET ARITHABORT OFF; SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON; SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF; SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

(@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 float,@p__linq__2 float,@p__linq__3 float,@p__linq__4 float)SELECT 
    [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Project1].[CENTER] AS [CENTER], 
    [Project1].[BOUNDS] AS [BOUNDS], 
    [Project1].[UTC_UPDATED] AS [UTC_UPDATED], 
    [Project1].[PLACE_ID] AS [PLACE_ID], 
    [Project1].[FORMATTED_ADDRESS] AS [FORMATTED_ADDRESS], 
    [Project1].[POST_CODE] AS [POST_CODE], 
    [Project1].[SOURCE] AS [SOURCE], 
    [Project1].[North] AS [North], 
    [Project1].[East] AS [East], 
    [Project1].[South] AS [South], 
    [Project1].[West] AS [West]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent1].[CENTER] AS [CENTER], 
        [Extent1].[BOUNDS] AS [BOUNDS], 
        [Extent1].[UTC_UPDATED] AS [UTC_UPDATED], 
        [Extent1].[PLACE_ID] AS [PLACE_ID], 
        [Extent1].[FORMATTED_ADDRESS] AS [FORMATTED_ADDRESS], 
        [Extent1].[POST_CODE] AS [POST_CODE], 
        [Extent1].[SOURCE] AS [SOURCE], 
        [Extent1].[North] AS [North], 
        [Extent1].[East] AS [East], 
        [Extent1].[South] AS [South], 
        [Extent1].[West] AS [West]
        FROM [dbo].[HST_GEOCODE_POINTS] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[UTC_UPDATED] > @p__linq__0) 
            AND ([Extent1].[North] >= @p__linq__1) 
            AND ([Extent1].[East] >= @p__linq__2) 
            AND ([Extent1].[South] <= @p__linq__3) 
            AND ([Extent1].[West] <= @p__linq__4)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[UTC_UPDATED] DESC, [Project1].[SOURCE] DESC
```

Note Bounds and Center are Geography types.  I initially used Intersects to find the correct Geocoded address but it was so slow I opted to find the rough NESW bounding box using SQL [they are simply doubles] and then intersect in code [.NET].

Comment: Did you consider/test Spatial Indexes before deciding to give up on SQL Server geography support? The non-clustered indexes are practically useless given that most of your seek predicates would be inequalities.

Comment: Start small, focus on your search predicate (where clause) and return one of the columns you're filtering on in your inner Project 1 table.  Confirm that this uses your non-clustered index.  Adding extra columns can confuse the optimizer.

Comment: There is no index at all that can be used. The leading column of your indexes is UTC and there is no condition on UTC in your query. Clustered index scan in your case is the only possible way to proceed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I tried for days and it was a huge margin slower than this query. I tried it again earlier and still no joy. I may be missing something though as when I tried to only use a Spatial Index it was 55x slower than this query.

Comment: @sepupic - I'd assumed by `UTC` they were referring to the `UTC_UPDATED` column. Still, as I say, the indexes aren't terribly useful because of all of the inequality tests.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes that is correct [about UTC being UTC_UPDATED], sorry I hand wrote that, updated my question accordingly. Also, what do you mean by inequality test? :)

Comment: Read [this post](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates) about index range scans. Then consider that you're effectively trying to scan across three ranges, two of which the server has no hope of identifying since it doesn't know the (presumed) relationship between `North` and `South`, nor the fact that the N-S range and E-W ranges in fact part of a 2d mapping.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the article.  Out of interest do you have any advice on how to get the Spatial Index working fast? I tried multiple times to get it working but it always seemed really slow or had a huge Read Count.  I am a developer writing SQL rather than a DBA so I am certain I am missing something?

Comment: At this point I think maybe your covering index is wider than PK! Why don't you include your table script in your post? If your PK and covering index have the same number of columns(I mean you add all columns as included), PK is just more "light weighting" because it has a narrower key (id vs UTC_UPDATED, North, East, South, West) so the leaf level is the same, byt the key is included in all inex's levels and in non-clustered it's wider

Comment: Based on your query it appears that you are running this through LINQ - you may want to add this piece of additional info

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Does that matter? Im profiling it using SQL tools rather than Visual Studio tools?

Comment: It just means you have no option to alter the actual query as it is autogenerated by LINQ. Also you might have limited options for using geographical data types in LINQ (but I'm not sure). There are also a few tricks to troubleshooting LINQ performance. One which I learnt the hard way is that to truly reproduce the real query plan you need to include all the `SET` options. I haven't used Redgate tools before. I assume this was generated straight from the Profiler trace rather than by feeding the query in?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hey, just to let you know that after your comments I revisited Spatial and its working like a dream. No idea why we couldnt get it working before [2 of us worked for days] but it works now so thanks. I think its because we put an Auto spatial index on rather than specifying levels. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whether SQL Server decides to do a scan or a seek depends on the selectivity of your query. In your case a scan is simply less expensive than a seek. Whether the index covers the query or not is not an issue. Please read about the [tipping point](http://sqlmag.com/database-administration/tipping-point).

Comment: Just a note, that's of course based on the estimates, which of course can be wrong. You can see it in your case by adding index hint, just to see how well / poorly the indexes behave. I wouldn't really recommend using that in production environment though

Comment: @Paweł Kucharski
He said he included *all the needed columns* in his index so about what lookups are you talking about?

Comment: I meant seek, fixed it now. Sorry about that.